# Use TWILIO for calling from computer

Tags: java, javascript, grails, twilio

I'm doing a project in grails and I have to implement a feature in which one can call on specific telephone number from 'web browser'. Is it possible with TWILIO ? If yes how can I do it? And do I need to install anything on my machine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio employee here.

Yes, you can use Twilio to do in browser phone calls, using [Twilio client](https://www.twilio.com/client). We have extensive documentation and a [Quick Start](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/java/client) guide in Java, which you can easily adapt for Grails.