# dial outbound with Twilio

Tags: java, rest, web-applications, twilio, voip

A previous question asked how to [dial from a web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23246699/).  Fair enough, but how do I dial a number from a soft-phone, like Jitsi, or an IP phone?

I would have to [build an app for that purpose, using the client](https://www.twilio.com/client)?

Oddly, incoming calls require almost no configuration for an IP phone and [dialing from the API](https://gist.github.com/THUFIR/f022faee0f2fd5c0e8af93c651045b31) is fairly easy.

Answer (score 1):

Think what you're looking for is SIP.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twilio-sip/sending-sip-how-it-works

**Making outbound and inbound calls using SIP domain**

Using Asterix as an example, the call flow from 5000@example.sip.com(SIP endpoint) to alice@example.sip.us1.twilio.com should look like this:

SIP End point ----> YOURNAME(Asterix PBX) ----> Internet -----> Twilio cloud ----> SIP domain(example.sip.us1.twilio.com) -----> alice

Now once the call reaches alice, web hooks can be used to make the necessary modifications as per individual use case.

You can also use this concept to make an outbound call so lets say alice.example.sip.us1.twilio.com calls 5000@example.sip.com this can be achieved by using [`<SIP>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sip) which is a part of the `<Dial>` verb in TwiML.

**Making outbound and inbound calls using SIP Trunking**

Check out the [getting started guide here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/sip-trunking/getting-started#configure-trunks).

The way SIP trunking works is best understood by the analogy of a pipe. You can route your calls towards the Twilio cloud (termination) or from Twilio cloud towards your infrastructure (origination). You also would need to set up an IP access list or credential list for security purposes.

Please let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: The diagram at https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twilio-sip/sending-sip-how-it-works fits your explanation.   How is the PBX not superfluous to that diagram?